# Cannot add an entity with a key that is already in use... I'm not inserting, just updating

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, .net-3.5

I'm not inserting.... The primary key is not an identity, Auto generated value is set to false... any ideas?

```
            var x= dataAccessDataContext.XTable.FirstOrDefault(xt=> xt.ID == Convert.ToInt32(id));

            if (x==null)
            {
                var newX = new Xtable
                                       {
                                           Data=id
                                       };
                dataAccessDataContext.XTable.InsertOnSubmit(newX);
                dataAccessDataContext.SubmitChanges();
            }
            else
            {
                x.Data=id
                dataAccessDataContext.SubmitChanges();//error happens right here when updating
            }
```

Comment: "Cannot add an entity with a key that is already in use" ..... is the error

Comment: Why you are updating Data through XTable, Why dont you update Data directly?

Comment: how? This is the only way I know how to do it

Comment: show your Xtable and Data Entity code.

Comment: is Data your primary key.(its silly to ask but it looks like that )

Comment: Apparently the dataAccessDataContext context has already loaded the entity once before. We cannot see that, show us the full code. Where are you creating your context?

Comment: I think the error is caused by other manipulation somewhere else and not by this piece of code. Try to create a new datacontext JUST before var x = data... and see if it still fails (or get the changeset)

Comment: Maarten and Pleun..... both of you guys were right... i went ahead and newed up the data context and that worked..... I was trying to to use one data context throughout the whole class.  I assumed that if you do SubmitChanges(), it clears the data context.  Maybe I missed something somewhere in the class, but newing it up worked.